# Alignment of price's location using CSS (Woo commerce Store)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, woocommerce

Problem with the alignement of price with the name(heading)

**CSS Code**

```
.mgrt-product-title .price {
 padding-left: 749px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#000;
}
```

You can check the present alignment here - [my store](https://grandchinaatl.com/thai-take-out-delivery-menu/). How to align prices to be all in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would erase the padding-left, use a `padding-right` instead (for example 100px or whatever you like) and add `float: right;` so the prices all align to the right side at the same distance.

```
.mgrt-product-title .price {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Your code worked well. Only one tip more, how to move button to be like this image? 

http://i.imgur.com/qoMKPdT.png

CSS is this:

`a.add_to_cart_button`

Comment: I can't say for sure without your real code, but adding `margin-right: 100px;` (i.e. the same value as you use for padding-right of the price) to the buttons should work.

Comment: Add same thing for this 
Do this for - .button.add_to_cart_button
float: right;
padding-right: 100px;

Then in  .mgrt-product-desc, add -
padding-bottom :20px

Comment: Yes, but i think that button need to move UP so will go close to image i have provided before. You dont think so ?

Comment: This code worked for me:

`.mgrt-product .button.add_to_cart_button {
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to make changes in padding, as your padding is to left depending on the size of the text your location of price varies. Keep padding from right and it will be set

```
.mgrt-product-title .price {
 float :right;
 padding-right: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#000;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your asnwer.  i added your padding, but still looks not good alligned. check again. Im trying to do something like this: http://i.imgur.com/qoMKPdT.png

Comment: aren't all the prices at the same place after doing this?

Comment: No looks messed up. Check the URL from first post, and see.. Looks Bad. This is the code i have currently:

`.mgrt-product-title .price {
  padding-left: 749px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#000;
}`

but looks bad..